# Как сделать переход на другое активти без возможности перехода на старое?

Tags: android, activity

К примеру есть `активти1` , `активити2` и `активити3`, к примеру я сначала перешел на `активити2` а от туда на `активити3`, но потом мне захотелось перейти с `активити3` на `активити1`, я делаю переход, но если я нажму кнопку назад то меня с `активити1` перебросит на `активити3` обратно, как избежать этого перехода ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

во втором `activity` после `startActivity` вызывайте `finish()`, В третьем активити вместо `startActivity`, вызывайте `finish()`. Тогда такой ситуации не повторится.

Answer (score 3):

Если `активити2` никогда не должна быть в стеке активити, то можно просто прописать параметр `android:noHistory="true"` для этой активити и не морочится со всякими финишами и стартами.

Пример как это должно выглядеть в манифесте:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:noHistory="true">
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - переопределить метод нажатия на кнопку "назад" и вместо стандартного действия запустить нужную активити:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Log.i(LOG, "onBackPressed");
    Intent intentToActivity = new Intent(this, ACTIVITy_CLASS_NAME.class);
    startActivity(intentToActivity);
}
```